# error while run npm run dev after adding extension for App Lock theme in shopify app MERN

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify, bundle, gemfile.lock

━━━━━━ Error ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Command failed with exit code 1: bundle install
Your lockfile was created by an old Bundler that left some things out.
Because of the missing DEPENDENCIES, we can only install gems one at a time, instead of installing 4 at a time.
You can fix this by adding the missing gems to your Gemfile, running bundle install, and then removing the gems from your Gemfile.
The missing gems are:
* mini_portile2 depended upon by nokogiri
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------

````
```
NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass

  warning << "* #{unmet_spec_dependency}, depended upon #{spec.full_name}, unsatisfied by #{@specs.find {|s| s.name == unmet_spec_dependency.name && !unmet_spec_dependency.matches_spec?(s.spec) }.full_name}"
                                                                                                                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in check_for_unmet_dependencies'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:123:in `each'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:123:in `block in check_for_unmet_dependencies'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:122:in `each'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:122:in `check_for_unmet_dependencies'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:100:in `call'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:71:in `call'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer.rb:254:in `install_in_parallel'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer.rb:209:in `install'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer.rb:89:in `block in run'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `open'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer.rb:71:in `run'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer.rb:23:in `install'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli/install.rb:62:in `run'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:257:in `block in install'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/settings.rb:131:in `temporary'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:256:in `install'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.23/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.23/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/bundle:33:in `load'
  C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/bundle:33:in `<main>'

```

## Environment

```
Bundler       2.3.23
  Platforms   ruby, x64-mingw-ucrt
Ruby          3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a9506d76391ac44bb2fe6e483fec952) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
  Full Path   C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  Config Dir  C:/ProgramData
RubyGems      3.3.23
  Gem Home    C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0/ruby/3.1.0
  Gem Path    C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0/ruby/3.1.0
  User Home   C:/Users/reeba
  User Path   C:/Users/reeba/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0
  Bin Dir     C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0/ruby/3.1.0/bin
OpenSSL
  Compiled    OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
  Loaded      OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
  Cert File   C:/Ruby31-x64/ssl/cert.pem
  Cert Dir    C:/Ruby31-x64/ssl/certs
Tools
  Git         2.32.0.windows.2
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      not installed
```

## Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2022-10-05
Git SHA           250d9d485d
Released Version  true
```

## Bundler settings

```
path
  Set for your local app (C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0/.bundle/config): "C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0"
```

## Gemfile

### Gemfile

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'shopify-cli', '2.25.0'
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
<No C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0/Gemfile.lock found>
```

--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/search?q=undefined+method+%60full_name%27+for+nil+NilClass&type=Issues

If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please fill in the new issue form located at https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/new?labels=Bundler&template=bundler-related-issue.md, and copy and paste the report template above in there.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Resolving dependencies...
Using ast 2.4.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using bugsnag 6.24.2
Using bundler 2.3.23
Using ffi 1.15.5
Using liquid 5.4.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.2
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.7.1
Using racc 1.6.0
Installing nokogiri 1.13.8 with native extensions
````

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error message.

First of all I've made the gem update and the bundler updates:
gem install bundler
gem update --system

And then:

You should find the Gemfile.lock file in the directory .../path to your installed folder/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.27.0/Gemfile.lock and copy in to the folder  C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0/

Generally it says - that the Gemfile.lock is not found:

#### Gemfile.lock

```
<No C:/Users/reeba/AppData/Local/shopify-cli-nodejs/Cache/vendor/ruby-cli/2.25.0/Gemfile.lock found>
```

That should help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

If you are using shopify cli 3.0+ and ruby 3.1.2 then copy Gemfile.lock from => *ruby path installed folder */lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-app/Gemfile.lock

OR in other versions it will be in *ruby path installed folder */lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/shopify-cli-2.27.0/Gemfile.lock

Add the Gemfile.lock in C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Local\shopify-cli-nodejs\Cache\vendor\ruby-cli\2.27.0

And also add same file at C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Local\shopify-cli-nodejs\Cache\vendor\theme-check\1.10.3